# Two of my custom user models cannot fail to login

Tags: django

I have created 3 custom user  models. However only one user under the models Users() is able to login in into a sells dashboard that I have created. I want the two user namelly, Buyer() and Supplier() to be able to login to the dashboard but not to the admin area. The following is my code. Please help me see the error.

```
# models.py 
# These are my three custom models
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, AbstractBaseUser, UserManager, BaseUserManager,   PermissionsMixin
from django.conf import settings

# Superuser model
class Users(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null="True")

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    # Returns username
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

# Supplier user model
class Supplier(AbstractBaseUser):
    sname = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Supplier Name', unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Phone Number')
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Email Address', null=True)
    physical_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Physical Address')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Describe yourself')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = Users()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'sname'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sname

# This model save inventory of a supplier
class Inventory(models.Model):
    pname = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Product Name')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Quantity (kgs)')
    measurement = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Measurement')
    orginal_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Original Price')
    commission = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Commission')
    selling_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Selling Price (MWK)')
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Supplier')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pname

# This model saves the transaction a buyer has made
class Transaction(models.Model):
    cust_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Customer Name')
    pid = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Product')
    quantity_r = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Quantity (KGS)')
    success = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    uid = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='User Id')
    # Calculates actual price
    def actual_price(self):
        return int(self.quantity_r) * int(self.pid.selling_price)

    # Returns customer name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cust_name

# Calculates total costs of suppliers products 
class SupplierProductCostView(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    sname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'home_supplierproductcostview'
        managed = False

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ' ' + self.sname + ' ' + str(self.price)

# Buyer user model
class Buyer(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Company Name')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Phone Number')
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Email Address')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Physical Address')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Describe your company')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = Users()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    # Returns username
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


   # forms.py
   # This is my registration and login form
from django import forms
from .models import Supplier, Buyer

# Custom supplier registration form
class SupplierRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    # Supplier registration form fields  
    class Meta:
        model = Supplier
        fields = ('sname', 'phone_number', 'email_address', 'physical_address', 'description')

    # Password check
    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']

# Custom buyer registration form
class BuyerRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    # Buyer registration form fields
    class Meta:
       model = Buyer
       fields = ('username', 'company_name', 'phone_number', 'email_address', 'address', 'description')

    # Password check
    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']

# Login form
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)


#views.py
# These are my login and logout views
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from users.forms import LoginForm

# User logs in to dashboard
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        loginform = LoginForm(request.POST)
        # Check if form is valid
        if loginform.is_valid():
            username = loginform.cleaned_data['username']
            password = loginform.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password = password)
            # If user does not exist  
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect(reverse('home'))
            else:
                context = {
                    'form':loginform,
                    'error': 'Could not login, Please try again...',
                }
                return render(request, 'users/index.html', context)
    loginform = LoginForm()
    context = {
        'form' : loginform,
    }
    # Returns login form
    return render(request, 'users/index.html', context)

# Logout
def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect(reverse('login'))
```

I extended the custom user model with a OneToOneField but now I Am getting this error "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "users_id" violates not-null constraint" apparently there is something wrong with my registration view. Can you help?

```
# Buyer registration view
def buyer_form_register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    buyer_form = BuyerRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if buyer_form.is_valid():
        # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
        new_user = buyer_form.save(commit=False)
        # Set the chosen password
        new_user.set_password(
            buyer_form.cleaned_data['password'])
        # Save the User object
        new_user.save()
        # Create the user profile
        return render(request, 'register/register_done.html')
else:
    buyer_form = BuyerRegistrationForm()
return render(request, 'register/register_buyer.html', {'buyer_form': buyer_form})

# Edited model
class Buyer(AbstractBaseUser):
    # New field
    users = models.OneToOneField(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Company Name')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Phone Number')
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Email Address')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Physical Address')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Describe your company')

    objects = Users()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have 3 custom user models, in settings.py you can only set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to one model.

[Extend your user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) with profiles (`OneToOneField`) instead to differentiate between the different user types.